# JQuery and F3 framework ajax issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have the following code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: '/index/city',
            data:  {massiv: 'qweqwe'},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg)
            { alert('success') },
            error: function (err)
            { console.log(err.responseText);}
        });
```

And the following code on php side:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

When I run it I get blank `$_POST` array. However, with firebug I can clearly see that I send POST query `massiv=qweqwe`. IF I run query with GET type, I can see it in `$_GET` array without any problems.

There is nothing in nginx and php-fpm logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found workaround using $.post, instead of $.ajax